# why mount an engine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have been reading about [rails engines](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Engine.html). Some blogs mention that you need to mount an engine and some says it is not needed.

I checked out a few engines and they do not have any instruction to mount that engine in their readme.

So why is mouting needed. I understand if I have a sinatra application then it needs to be mounted. However what if I have an new gem that just provides you are url to `/happy` and it displays 'happy monday`. For this if I create an engine do I need to mount it ?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, you mount an engine if it is going to need to be to have routes to it. If the engine doesn't expose controller actions, the mounting is not needed. An example of this is an engine that is responsible for implementing the submission of a common form element on a number of forms. The parent form (and action, etc) is responsible for the actual routes and so forth so it doesn't need to be mounted. But if the engine added a complete form that needed to be submitted you might want to put a controller with action(s) to handle that form in the engine. Then you need to mount the engine so those controller actions are exposed to HTTP. Perhaps there are other reasons to mount an engine -- if so, hopefully someone can fill us in.

Note that if you run `rails engine new -h` it has a `--mountable` option which corresponds to `Generate mountable isolated application`.